# The type or namespace name 'ASPSnippets' could not be found ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-assembly

I have created few simple pages in ASP.NET on my local computer and they are working fine on localhost. I have used an external Facebook Connect API for Facebook Connect integration with my website. But when I deployed project to live server, it gives following Error:

`Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ASPSnippets' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

The reference DLL is in the Bin Directory and it should be working fine. Dont know what is going wrong! :'(

**`Here is the complete error Details:`**

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ASPSnippets' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 5:  using System.Web.UI;
Line 6:  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
Line 7:  using ASPSnippets.FaceBookAPI;
Line 8:  using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
Line 9:

Source File: c:\HostingSpaces\theitfor\projects.theitfort.com\wwwroot\HamaraPakistan\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 7

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Web.Entity.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\aa2af9fb\80cee35a\App_Web_wycatr4n.dll" /debug- /optimize+ /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /warnaserror-  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\aa2af9fb\80cee35a\App_Web_wycatr4n.0.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\aa2af9fb\80cee35a\App_Web_wycatr4n.1.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\aa2af9fb\80cee35a\App_Web_wycatr4n.2.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\aa2af9fb\80cee35a\App_Web_wycatr4n.3.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\aa2af9fb\80cee35a\App_Web_wycatr4n.4.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\aa2af9fb\80cee35a\App_Web_wycatr4n.5.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\aa2af9fb\80cee35a\App_Web_wycatr4n.6.cs"

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929

for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\HostingSpaces\theitfor\projects.theitfort.com\wwwroot\HamaraPakistan\Default.aspx.cs(7,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ASPSnippets' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\HostingSpaces\theitfor\projects.theitfort.com\wwwroot\HamaraPakistan\RegistrationStep2.aspx.cs(8,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ASPSnippets' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18044

**Any good thoughts??**

Comment: This is obvious, but, make sure you have added the reference, the proper using and make sure you didn't perform any clean solution because that might have deleted the file. As a good practice, it's better to add the external dll to a folder in the same level as the solution and the add a solution folder into the project pane in visual studio and, finally, add the reference in the project

Comment: One thing I've always found with Visual Studio is you will get these errors when you try to compile, but it's unable to build the reference because of another, unrelated, error. Are you getting any other errors or just this one?